# On Click of anchor tag get Current row value

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I want to access Current row ItemID value on Click of Anchor tag

```js
$scope.Test12 = function() {
  ID = document.getElementById("ItemId"); //Want to access Clicked ItemID Value
}
```

```html
<tr ng-repeat="customer in customers">

  <td><a ng-href='#here' ng-click='Test12()' onclick="OpenDialog()">{{customer.OldAccount_x002f_Cost_x0020_Elem}}</a>
  </td>

  <td>{{customer.NewAccount_x002f_CostElement}}</td>
  <td>{{customer.Description}}</td>
  <td>
    <input id="ItemId" type="text" name="ID" value={{customer.ID}}>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass `customer` in the [ngClick](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick), then you can access properties of `customer` object.

```
<tr ng-repeat="customer in customers">  
    <td><a ng-href='#here' ng-click='Test12(customer)' onclick="OpenDialog()">{{customer.OldAccount_x002f_Cost_x0020_Elem}}</a></td>        
</tr>
```

*Controller*

```
$scope.Test12 = function(customer){
    ID=customer.ID
}
```

Comment: Worked for me!!